# How do I make the calculation in the WHERE clause also be a result?

Tags: mysql

This is a very basic question I'm sure but... I have the MySQL query below there's the ST_Distance_Sphere calculation in the Where clause. That's calculating distance so I want it to also show up in the results and called "Distance." How do I modify this query so that it will show that calculation in the results?

```
SELECT * from users
INNER JOIN addresses on users.id = addresses.user_id
WHERE (ST_Distance_Sphere(
    point(addresses.GoogleLong,addresses.GoogleLat),
    point(-81.775085, 26.24476)
)
* 0.000621371) <6;
```

Comment: Put the calculation in the `SELECT` clause as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the calculation in the `SELECT` clause.

You can use `HAVING` to avoid doing the calculation twice.

```
SELECT *, ST_Distance_Sphere(
            point(addresses.GoogleLong,addresses.GoogleLat),
            point(-81.775085, 26.24476)
        ) * 0.000621371 AS distance 
from users
INNER JOIN addresses on users.id = addresses.user_id
HAVING distance <6;
```